# Rules on when to use quotes and when not to in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, quotes

When starting out learning `R`, it can be very confusing in which cases you have to put something in quotes / quotation marks and when you don't.

For example, when calling the column `mpg` from `mtcars`, I use quotes when using the `[` notation but omit them when using the `$`. The output however is identical.

```r
unquoted <- mtcars$mpg

quoted <- mtcars[,"mpg"]

identical(unquoted,quoted)
#> [1] TRUE
```

It get's even more complicated when I use tidyverse functions. Are there some general rules on when to use quotes and when not to?

PS: I'm asking this question on behalf of many confused students.

Answer (score 3):

Putting quotes on something makes it into a character constant.  Leaving them off means the object will be taken to be an expression which could be evaluated.

The tricky thing is that R is very flexible, and the functions you call can ask it to treat character constants as expressions and then evaluate them, or they can convert expressions to character constants without ever evaluating them.

For your examples:

In `mtcars$mpg`, the `mpg` is given as a name (i.e. a simple expression), but when evaluating `mtcars$mpg` R converts it to a character value and looks up the column with that name.  You could have done the conversion yourself, i.e. `mtcars$"mpg"` is fine and gives you the same thing, it's just extra typing.

In `mtcars[,"mpg"]`, you are explicitly giving the name of the column as a character constant.  If you had written `mtcars[, mpg]` then R would assume you wanted to evaluate `mpg` and use its value to select a column.  This is inconsistent with the previous syntax, because `[` is different from `$`.  You just need to remember that.

Many `tidyverse` functions use more complicated rules to change how R evaluates things.  They push the R flexibility a lot.  The rules they use are consistent within `tidyverse` functions, but won't be consistent with other R functions.

So what is the general rule?  There isn't one.  The only advice I can think of is "read the help page for the function you are using."  And if you write your own functions, don't be too clever:  have pity on the poor user.

Comment: “Putting quotes on something makes it into a character constant” — Except when it doesn’t  (neither of the following introduce character constants: `"f"()`, `f("x"  = v)`, and kinda-sorta `"x" <- v` and `a$"b"` …)

Comment: Yes, in all of those cases it does make a character constant, but in all of those cases R will "treat character constants as expressions".

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by “treat character constants as expressions”: they are always expressions anyway. — Did you mean “… as names”? And when I look at `quote("f"())[[1L]]`, I see that a name, not a character constant. — Either way, it’s this behaviour of *treating* them as names which I was referring to (and which I am very unhappy about).

Comment: I was quoting my answer, which is imprecise because I wasn't directing it at language lawyers.  Yes, in this context, character constants are treated as names.  In your `quote()` example, you are looking at it after some processing.  If you look at `getParseData(parse(text='"f"()'))` you will see it as a string constant.  You shouldn't be unhappy about it, any more than you should be unhappy that the sky is blue.

Comment: It leads to tons of confusion, not just for beginner R programmers but even for advanced ones. And it’s an utterly unnecessary behaviour: it’s plain bad language design. — So I think I’m well justified being unhappy with it. (The `getParseData()` result isn’t really relevant here, since that is literally referring to the *source code*, not the parsed expression. *R* treats the expression as not-a-string; the fact that that’s different from the code entered by the user is precisely my point.)

Comment: Backtick notation for non-syntactic names wasn't added to R until version 1.8.0 in 2003.  I don't remember if S used the same rules for quoting names, but there had been at least 8 years of people using quotes on names before that, so outlawing them would have caused a lot of disruption.  So yes, it was a bad language design, and it was dealt with more than 20 years ago, but back-compatibility means the old ugly syntax still works.  Just don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general rules from the top of my head:

##### When to use quotes

- Filenames
- Arguments to functions
- Colors
- Column Names

  - if used within `[`
  - if used as arguments within functions which are not part of the tidyverse (see below)
- library calls:

  - installation: `install.packges("mypackage")`
  - importing: `library("mypackage")`(here, you don't *have* to quote)

##### When **not** to use quotes

- Objects in your environment
- Numbers, if you want to treat them as such
- `TRUE`/`FALSE`
- Column Names

  - if used within tidyverse functions (e.g. `group_by`, `mutate`, `summarise`, `ggplot`, `pivot_*`, `*_join`)
  - if used with the `$` sign (e.g. `df$mycolumn`. However, you *could* use quotes)